# How can I get VIEWSTATE Value from webpages for Python web client prgoram?

Tags: asp.net, python, client, web, viewstate

I wanna get VIEWSTATE value from webpage that I use.( this site was wrote in ASP.NET) This value is change more quickly and I want to get this when I connect to site and use it in my Python program.

Any Ideas.
please give me an example
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use lxml.html to parse the page and xpath (see [tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#using-xpath-to-find-text)) to get the hidden form field corresponding to VIEWSTATE.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx for info on how VIEWSTATE is apparently used.

Comment: Keeping in mind that any site with even a modicum of time spent on security encrypts its view state, making the resulting data mostly useless.